# Why does it reload the page when using Link with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I am using the Link component of next to redirect to other pages but when I click it reloads the page completely according to the documentation of next it is as follows how it is used

```
<Link href='/rute'>
   <a>Contenido</a>
</Link>
```

I have the routes and the content in an array to go through it

```
export const Navheader = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'home',
        link: '/',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'laptops',
        link: '/detailPage',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'delivery',
        link: '/deliveryPage',
    },

    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'legal active',
        link: '/legalPage',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'secure payment',
        link: '/paymentPage',
    },
    
];
```

a component with array props

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Navitems = ({ navbar }) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        <>
            <li className='nav-items'>
                <Link href={navbar.link}>
                    <a
                        className={
                            router.pathname == navbar.link
                                ? ' nav-links active'
                                : ' nav-links'
                        }
                    >
                        {navbar.title}
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </li>
        </>
    );
};
Navitems.propTypes = {
    navbar: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
export default Navitems;
```

And in the navigation finally with my array

```
{
    Navheader.map((navbar) => (
       <Navitems key={navbar.id} navbar={navbar} />
    ))
}
```

I also have simpler buttons where the same thing happens

Remove the / that was one of the things that I saw in a similar question but it does not work if someone knows why this happens I will thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

**Background**

Next.js is a static page generator and server side renderer framework. So it creates pages that come from a server (or cache) so the pages are loaded when you navigate. Using `next/link` (the `<Link>` tag) optimizes this by doing prefetching of cached static pages which makes the loading really snappy.

**Answer**

This optimization does not happen when you are running in dev mode so you will only see the `next/link` optimization working with the production build. Also this only prefetches static pages, so it will still need to load SSR pages.

That said, if you are looking for a solution that does not "reload" then you need a pure react solution. But you will be missing the SEO benefits of using next.

Answer (score -1):

import `NextLink` from `next/link` for SPA Pages

Comment: He is already importing from next/link.